# Is it possible to unit test a method which have setter and getter using mockito and powermock

Tags: java, junit, mockito, powermock

I am writing unit test for a legacy code which is basically setting and getting value in the method using chain stub, the class I am testing does not have dependency on other classes so I do not have mock anything but have a method like this

```
public class SampleClass {
  public void process(Context context){
    context.getState().setValue(MathUtil.roundToThree(context.getState().getValue());
  }
}
```

The test class I have written is as follows:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class TestSampleClass{
 SampleClass sample = new SampleClass();
 @Test
 public void testProcess(){
 Context context = Mockito.mock(Context.class, Mockito.RETURNS_DEEP_STUBS);
 Mockito.when(context.getState().getValue()).thenReturn(4.12345);
 sample.process(context);
 assertEquals(4.123,context.getState().getValue(),0.0);
 }
}
```

Test case is failing because it is returing 4.12345 due to Mockito.when() but I am not sure how do I test the value in `context` object after calling the `process()` method.

I can not change the source code. 
Intializing Context is very difficult because it depends on so many other Classes. Please help.

Comment: I am not sure about that but you don't set the value, I think you should try something like:
 context.getState().setValue(4.12345);

Comment: Why cannot you just test `MathUtil.roundToThree()` method with a very simple unit-test?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your stub `State` object doesn't know that the value returned by `getValue()` should be the last value that was passed to `setValue()`.

The stub created by Mockito doesn't automatically pick up that you have a getter and setter and the getter should return what the setter was last called with.  It's just a dumb stub that only does what you've told it to do, and you haven't told it to do anything when `setValue()` is called.

It may be simplest to verify that `setValue` was called with the rounded value, rather than attempt to fetch it from `getValue()`:

```
    Mockito.verify(context.getState()).setValue(AdditionalMatchers.eq(4.123, 0.0));
```

Another approach is to create a test `State` class that has real getters and setters, and use that in your tests.  Of course, whether or not you can do this depends on how many other methods this class has.  If you were to write such a class (I named it `TestState` in the code below), the test code would look like the following:

```
@Test
public void testProcess2(){
    Context context = Mockito.mock(Context.class);
    Mockito.when(context.getState()).thenReturn(new TestState());
    context.getState().setValue(4.12345);
    sample.process(context);
    assertEquals(4.123,context.getState().getValue(),0.0);
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I would go with your first approach.